# Python datetime.strptime works only on dev environment

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-datetime

This is my code:

```
for i in report:
    reports.append({
        'total':i['vends__sum'],
        'date':datetime.strptime(i['month'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    })
```

This works on my OSX dev environment (virtualenv env django 1.5)

But on my production server (ubuntu 12.04 virtualenv django 1.5) it does not work with this error:

```
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
must be string, not datetime.datetime
Exception Location: /var/www/webapps/cirostats/products/templatetags/product_tags.py in show_main_chart, line 41
```

Line 41 is

> 'date':datetime.strptime(i['month'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

I cant figure out why works on the one environment and not the other? Who is wrong here, the dev or prod?

```
Prod : Python 2.7.3
Dev: Python 2.7.1
```

MORE:

This is how report is made:

```
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month','timestamp')
qs = objects.extra({'month':truncate_date})
report = qs.values('month').annotate(Sum('vends')).order_by('month')
```

Comment: Well I is this: {'vends__sum': 328, 'month': u'2013-06-01 00:00:00'}

Comment: Not on production, it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your production environment, `i['month']` is **already** a `datetime.datetime` object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> example = u'2013-06-01 00:00:00'
>>> example = datetime.datetime.strptime(example, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> example = datetime.datetime.strptime(example, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be string, not datetime.datetime
```

So to find the difference between your production and development environments, you'll have to trace what produces `report` and find out why one environment produces strings, and the other produces `datetime.datetime` objects instead.

If you are using datetime operations on your server backend, take into account that some SQL servers support native datetime arithmetic, but SQLite (the database you usually develop against) *does not*. PostgreSQL will produce `datetime` objects, SQLite produces strings.

You'll either want to switch how you handle dates here based on your database settings, or detect if you already have a `datetime` object and skip parsing.

Comment: Ok, this is what "i" is in the loop: datetime.strptime("%s" % i['month'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") on my dev env. Ok, but what you say makes sense, let me sniff around

Comment: @Harry: I've added an example, where we pass first a string, then the result of `.strptime()` to `.strptime()` to reproduce your exception.

Comment: Check my update in my question how i create it, I see that Im actually creating a datetime object, how would you make it a string and still leave my logic in tact?

Comment: @Harry: Then your production database produces `datetime.datetime` objects.

Comment: Ah, stupid me, production is POstgres and dev is sqlite! Must be that yes. Fixed it by just removing the stptime completely.

Answer (score 1):

strptime results in a datetime object which is, in your debug environment printable, for production you need to change it to:

```
datetime.strptime(i['month'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").format('how you would like to display it')
```

But since you strptime is normally used to convert a date/time to a datetime object from a string I am not sure why you are not just using the string directly. i.e.
'date':i['month']

Comment: Yup, I edned up using it directly, but this does not work as expected in dev, but thats ok..

Comment: You could always make it conditional based on the type.